# Using a "array of controls" as parameters on String.Format()

Tags: c#, vb.net

I use a string for a query that goes like this:

```
Dim auxstring as String
auxstring = String.Format("val1 = {0}, val2 = {1}, valn ={n}", control1.Value,   control2.Value, controln.Value)
```

What I want to do is to transform the String.Format into something more readable like so:

```
<object like an array>.<value1> = data1
<object like an array>.<value2> = data2
<object like an array>.<valuen> = datan

<other object like an array>.<value1> = control1.property
<other object like an array>.<value2> = control1.property
<other object like an array>.<valuen> = control1.property

auxstring = String.Format(<object like an array with values>, <object like an array with controls.properties>)
```

For the sake of readability :)

Comment: Why is this question marked as `C#`? Your example is written in `VB.NET`. Would the less specific `.NET` tag be more appropriate?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to asking in this site, both languages would help :)

Comment: I didn't mean to ask that in a pejorative way, it was meant as a clarifying question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to go about this, whether you view this as an improvement on your existing code is a matter of opinion.

```
List<string> vals = new List<string>();
int[] data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    vals.Add(string.Format("val{0} = {1}", i + 1, data[i]));
}

string auxstring = string.Join(",", vals.ToArray());
```

This simple example uses an integer array, but it would be trivial to change that to whatever type and access a property off of the indexed item (in the loop) instead of the indexed value itself.

Comment: Not quite what I want, would like to use a list of controls like this
: String.Format(<string with {n} thingies>, <list of controls.properties>)

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is to transform the String.Format into something
>   more readable

Use the line extension symbol(_):

```
    auxstring = String.Format("val1 = {0}, val2 = {1}, valn ={n}", _
                              control1.Value, _
                              control2.Value, _
                              controln.Value)
```

Just remember it needs a space before it and has to the last character on  the line.

If you want something more succinct I would suggest overloading the format function.  This way you can leave Option Strict On and not have to worry about issues with late binding.

```
 Dim Values() As Integer = {0, 1, 2}

 Dim ValueString As String = Format("val", Values)  

 Public Function Format(Of T)(Identifier As String, ObjectArray() As T) As String
     Format = ""
     For I = 0 To ObjectArray.Length - 1
         Format += String.Format(Identifier + I.ToString + " = {0} , ", ObjectArray(I).ToString)
     Next
     Format = Format.TrimEnd({" "c, ","c})
 End Function
```

ValueString will look like this, `"val0 = 0 , val1 = 1 , val2 = 2"`
This will accept any array object with a ToString method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of your properties, and then dynamically generate your format string to match the number of properties:

```
    Dim properties = {
        control1.property,
        control2.property,
        control3.property}

    Dim formatString = String.Join(", ", properties.Select(Function(_trash, i) String.Format("val{0} = {{{0}}}", i)))

    Dim auxstring = String.Format(formatString, properties)
```